# Как ускорить MAX(ID) в секционированной по дате таблице?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Работаю с MS SQL Server.
Есть таблица в которой поле ID - это кластеризованный индекс.
С фрагментацией индекса всё ок(почти 0%).
Таблица секционирована по месяцам.
Хочу получить максимальное значение ключа:

```
SELECT MAX(ID_CONTACT) FROM CMS_Contact_Info
```

Оптимизатор почему-то решил, что просмотр всей таблицы - это хорошая идея, хотя казалось бы: нужно просто спуститься по дереву кластеризованного индекса к последней странице и на ней найти максимальное значение ключа.
Вместо этого он берёт наиболее лёгкий некластеризованный индекс и полностью просматривает его.
Если добавить хинт "WITH (INDEX (IDX_ID_CONTACT))", то ситуация ещё хуже.
Пробовал и так:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID_CONTACT FROM CMS_Contact_Info ORDER BY ID_CONTACT DESC
```

Всё равно план +/- такой же.
Помогите понять в чём я ошибаюсь и как сделать запрос моментальным?
План выполнения прилагаю:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть, если вам нужно знать максимальный ID этой таблицы, то стоит его записывать в другую таблицу и вычитывать, когда это нужно? Стоимость нахождения MAX(ID) станет минимально возможной

Comment: Да, но это дополнительная сущность и логика.
В MS SQL есть расширенные свойства таблицы(extended properties), там можно создать свойство, например "MaxID", и обновлять его после каждой загрузки.
Но мне хочется понять, почему мои доводы не верны, чтобы изменить представление о подкапотном пространстве этой СУБД и как с этим жить без "костылей" в виде дополнительных таблиц и расширенных свойств.

Comment: Я не смогу ответить на ваш вопрос, т.к. я глубоко не изучал индексацию в SQL

Comment: Это какая то мистика. Все известные мне СУБД select max(id) делают по нужному индексу и как вы и предполагаете, беря только нужное значение из дерева. И ms sql не исключение, только что проверил на такой БД. Можно только предположить что индекса по этому полю нет. убедитесь еще раз что индекс действительно есть

Comment: Либо индекс `IDX_ID_CONTACT` у вас тоже секционирован. Индекс должен быть создан НЕ секционированным, чтобы оптимизатор для MAX/MIN мог брать одно последнее/первое значение из него.

Comment: @i-one вы правы, благодарю! Проверил на НЕ секционированной, но очень похожей таблице и там действительно всё отрабатывает мгновенно, кол-во чтений = 4, в то время как у моей таблицы кол-во чтений 1,7 млн страниц. Странно, казалось бы: ну пусть у тебя 100 секций, иди в последнюю не пустую секцию, спустись по её дереву к последней её странице и возьми там строку с максимальным ключом.
Причина потери производительности понятна, а ​вот если этому есть ещё и объяснение, буду рад
​ознакомиться)

Comment: Я так понимаю, что у вас в таблице есть какой-то столбец с датой. И `ID_CONTACT`, вероятно, увеличивается с увеличением этой даты, т.е. самая поздняя дата имеет также и самый большой ID. Но оптимизатор об этом не может знать наверняка, ему нужны гарантии. Ведь не запрещается, например, подправить исторические данные и вставить самый большой ID (на текущий момент времени), скажем, в 27-ю секцию. Соответственно, просто пойти и взять последнее значение в последней секции недостаточно. Нужно пройти все секции.

Comment: Другое дело, что и с секциями, всё-таки, оптимизатор мог бы поступить умнее: взять последнее значение на последней странице индекса `IDX_ID_CONTACT` в каждой секции, затем взять максимум таких значений по всем секциями (т.е. найти максимум максимумов). Но такая логика, по-видимому, просто не реализована в оптимизаторе. Однако не секционированный индекс на секционированной таблице должен сработать в данном случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл решение:

```
SELECT MAX(PARTITION_MAX) AS MAX_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PARTITION_NUMBER
    FROM sys.partitions
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('CMS_CONTACT_INFO')
) AS PARTITION_NUMBERS
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT MAX(ID_CONTACT) AS PARTITION_MAX
    FROM CMS_CONTACT_INFO
    WHERE $partition.pfMonthsByDatetime2(DT_CONTACT) = PARTITION_NUMBERS.PARTITION_NUMBER
) AS PARTITION_MAX
```

В первом подзапросе получаем номера всех секций, тут обращение к системному представлению sys.partitions - это быстро. Затем, в CROSS APPLY, находим максимум для каждой секции - это тоже быстро, т.к. таблица отсортирована по ID. В конце, из полученных максимумов каждой секции, находим максимум для всей таблицы.

---

План запроса стал страшнее, а вот время(4мс против 39 700мс) и количество чтений(470 против 851 550) улучшились многократно:

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Сергей Олонцев](https://mvp.microsoft.com/ru-ru/PublicProfile/5000106?fullName=Sergey%20Olontsev), благодарю за исчерпывающий доклад "[Практическое применение секционирования в SQL Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrBV7UoOGPQ&t=3066s)". Не зря MVP по SQL Server)

Comment: +1, но такое решение требует разрешения на объекте не ниже `VIEW DEFINITION` (иначе _sys.partitions_ не вернёт информацию о секциях).

Comment: i-one можно этот скрипт завернуть в хранимую процедуру с правами владельца(WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER) и возвращать из неё число

Comment: Это, опять же, смотря кто владелец (точнее сказать, какие у него права). Если _dbo_ (или если сам запрос исполняется в контексте прав _dbo_), то и нет проблем. Смысл моей ремарки был в том, что так или иначе данный способ требует немного больше прав, чем прямой `SELECT`. Конечно же, в зависимости от стратегии разграничения доступа, это может быть как важно так и не важно совершенно.